# При запуске процедуры из пакета исключение ORA-06508: PL/SQL: could not find program unit being called

Tags: oracle, plsql

Есть пара пакетов с процедурами.

Вызываю процедуру, она завершается с ошибкой:

> ORA-06508: PL/SQL: could not find programm unit called

Если захожу в процедуру в PL/SQL Developer через Debug по шагам, то процедура выполняется нормально и отрабатывает корректно. Все используемые пакеты имеют статус `VALID`.

Подскажите, в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: посмотрите , может что-то неверно скомпилировалось из объектов или пакетов, которые используются у вас в процедуре: select 
   comp_id, 
   comp_name, 
   version, 
   status, 
   namespace, 
   schema 
from 
   dba_registry;

Comment: Смотрел. Ничего похожего там нет.

Comment: посмотрите здесь (может у вас аналогичная проблема с синонимами): http://www.sql.ru/forum/actualutils.aspx?action=gotomsg&tid=918347&msg=12113567

Comment: Нет. Синонимов вообще нет

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это поведение свазано с состоянем пакета. Обратимся к подглаве [Package State](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/plsql-packages.html#GUID-08E1FC04-9EF3-4396-83C6-4812F8ECABF4):

> The values of the variables, constants, and cursors that a package declares (in either its specification or body) comprise its package state.
>
> If a PL/SQL package declares at least one variable, constant, or cursor, then the package is **stateful**; otherwise, it is **stateless**.

Если в пакете определена как минимум одна переменная, константа или курсор, то пакет после инициализаци получает состояние, которое сохраняется до окончания сессии. Состояние пакета может стать недействительным, одной из причин этого является рекомпиляция пакета:

> The package body is recompiled.
>
> If the body of an instantiated, stateful package is recompiled (either explicitly, with the "ALTER PACKAGE Statement", or implicitly), the next invocation of a subprogram in the package causes Oracle Database to discard the existing package state and raise the exception ORA-04068.

> After PL/SQL raises the exception, a reference to the package causes Oracle Database to re-instantiate the package, which re-initializes it. Therefore, previous changes to the package state are lost.

После возникновения ошибки, пакеты автоматически реинициализируются, старое их состояние теряется и появляется новое.

Возможное решение, пересмотреть дизайн кода и убрать все переменные, константы или курсоры, объявленные вне функций или процедур, другими словами создать пакет без состояния. Но ничего страшного, если это не предоставляется возможным, при повторном запуске ошибка не должна возникнуть.

Воспроизводимый пример:

```
create or replace package pack1 as
    val varchar2 (8) := 'pack';
end;
/
create or replace package pack2 as
    function foo return varchar2;
end;
/
create or replace package body pack2 as 
    function foo return varchar2 is
    begin 
        return pack1.val||'2';
    end;
end;
/
select pack2.foo from dual;

FOO
--------
pack2
```

В другой сессии заново скомпилируем пакет:

```
alter package pack1 compile;

Package altered.
```

Теперь, в первой сессии вызов вызовет ошибку, так как состояние пакета `pack1` потеряно:

```
select pack2.foo from dual;

Error report -
ORA-04068: existing state of packages has been discarded
ORA-04061: existing state of package "DB.PACK1" has been invalidated
ORA-04065: not executed, altered or dropped package "DB.PACK1"
ORA-06508: PL/SQL: could not find program unit being called: "DB.PACK1"
ORA-06512: at "DB.PACK2", line 4

select pack2.foo from dual;

FOO
--------
pack2
```

Comment: Ваш ответ безусловно намного более полезен, чем мой! Надеюсь, кому-нибудь это будет полезно =)

Comment: Я уже плохо помню за давностью лет. Вроде у меня при перезапуске пакет не рекомпилился, отсюда и возник этот вопрос. Спасло только пересоздание сессии.

Comment: _при перезапуске пакет не рекомпилился_, он  не рекомпилится, а инициализирутся заново. Но это не важно, главное чтобы трудящиеся поняли, что если код изменился, то до того, как он будет запущен, все его "следы" в памяти должны быть удалены.

Answer (score 1):

Такая ошибка возникает когда в сессии номер 1 было обращение к пакету, потом другая сессия перекомпилила пакет, и снова сессия номер 1 запустила его. То есть суть в том что посторонняя сессия инициализировала для себя пакет, но после перекомпиляции эта инициализация не может считаться валидной, поскольку пакет мог быть изменен до степени не соответствия параметров инициализации с новой структурой\логикой пакета.
Помогает запуск процедуры в новой сессии.